# HIPI compile fail: class file for com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGDecodeParam not found

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, ant, java-7

I was compiling HIPI framework using ant on Hadoop 2.6.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 and got this error:

```
Buildfile: /home/jinjunho/hipi/src/build.xml

setup:

test_settings:

all:
    [javac] Compiling 23 source files to /home/jinjunho/hipi/lib
    [javac] /home/jinjunho/hipi/src/hipi/image/io/MetadataReader.java:34: error: cannot access JPEGDecodeParam
    [javac]         return JpegMetadataReader.readMetadata(_ubis);
    [javac]                                  ^
    [javac]   class file for com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGDecodeParam not found
    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] 1 error

BUILD FAILED /home/jinjunho/hipi/src/build.xml:25: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 1 second
```

From the internet I found that the above package is not included in java 7 (..really?). Is there any solution to this problem? Or do I really have to recompile it with java 6?

If I can, I would like to compile it with java 7. Any suggestion or solution would be appreciated.

(ps. I found a solution from the internet which uses "-XDignore.symbol.file" option of javac, but it didn't work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some people who may had same problem as me, it was simply Java version problem-HIPI must be compiled using Java 1.6

I think I can make later versions of Java to compile HIPI, but I haven't tried it. Instead, I just simply used hipi jar file located in the source package without compiling the source by myself.